# Can you publish PowerBI Reports to SSRS 2014?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

We need to be able to publish PowerBI reports locally (versus publishing to the PowerBI service/website).  We're running SQL Server 2014, because we do not feel SQL Server 2016 is mature enough to use yet (maybe in a year or two).

What options do we have for publishing PowerBI reports to some local resource (e.g. SSRS, a static web page, etc.)?  Can we publish to SSRS 2014 (in SQL Server 2014)?

Comment: You can publish any file to SSRS 2014, but it won't render in the browser (it will download the file and open in Power BI Desktop, assuming you have it installed).

Answer (score 2):

Currently, only technical preview of SSRS <strike>2016</strike> vNext supports PowerBI integration. [SSRS Blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlrsteamblog/2016/10/27/technical-preview-of-power-bi-reports-in-sql-server-reporting-services-now-available/)

One option to run it locally today is to manually distribute PBIX files, and view them in PowerBI desktop.

Or you can run that technical preview, of course. You could set up a separate instance solely for PowerBI reports, and carry on using 2014 for everything else.

Comment: I have been told it is a preview of SSRS vNext not SSRS 2016. But otherwise I agree with your answer.

Comment: here is the blog post where they clarify its SQL vNext: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlrsteamblog/2016/12/16/power-bi-reports-in-sql-server-reporting-services-feedback-on-the-technical-preview/

Answer (score 2):

You can publish to an on-premises [Pyramid Analytic](http://pyramidanalytics.com/) server.

> Microsoft collaborated with Pyramid Analytics to develop the Power BI
>   Desktop. Pyramid Analytics’ on-premise server-based technology
>   complements Microsoft SQL Server Analysis Services, leveraging all the
>   features of the Microsoft BI stack. You can now publish a Power BI
>   Desktop file to Pyramid Analytics Server, and more features will be
>   added over the next few months to enable seamless integration. We’re
>   excited to collaborate in accelerating the delivery of innovative BI
>   features that customers want and need most.

[Source](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/landing/pyramid/).